# Internet Explorer - Open File Dialog keyboard shortcurt

Tags: internet-explorer, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the keyboard shortcut to open a "Browse file" dialog"?

The enter key works in Chrome but in IE it submits the form.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its spacebar in IE.

Accidentally found it after hours of trying and reading documentation on shortcuts.

Comment: keyboard nav in is IE is tabs, shift tab, enter/space.